# What algebraic structure is if a vector space is immersed on a intersection between plane-hyperplane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

Usually we refer to a vector space immersed into a plane or an hyperplane.
I want to understand what happens if I have this structure

- a vector or a vector space
- 2 different planes: a plane & hyperplane
- plane and hyperplane are intersected between them

I want to immerse vector space in this *2-different plane intersection*. 
What algebraic structure is ? What happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call them "2 different planes", I assume neither is a subset of the other. In that case, their intersection will either be a line (a one-dimensional vector space) or the origin (a zero-dimensional vector space). if you allow one to be a subset of the other, then obviously a plane is also a possibility.

Vector spaces are not "immersed in" a plane or hyper-plane. Instead they are almost exactly what a "hyper-plane" is. A hyper-plane is a geometric object with the property that given any two points in it, the entire line passing through those points is also contained in the hyper-plane. Because of this property, if you choose a point in the hyperplane to act as origin, then there are natural geometric constructions that define vector addition and scalar multiplication between all points of the hyper-plane, which makes the hyper-plane a vector space.

Comment: You say that "they intersection will be one-dimensional vector space": but is possible to view this 'line' or 'origin point' like a topological space? My idea is to work with that like a mathematical filter to transform vector space from a subset morphism (a generator is a subspace usually) to induce from subspace a property for vector space like a winding number. So..theoretically I try to have an auto-intersection, is possible to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you seem to be using words without much understanding of what they mean. *Any* subset of a topological space is also a topological space. Vector spaces are contractible, so their topological properties are trivial. For finite dimensional vector spaces over a given field, their behavior/nature is entirely dictated by the number of dimensions, so they allow only that one well-known classification. With infinite-dimensional vector spaces, there is more variation. They are classified using Lie theory.

Comment: Ok, I read here about contractible space https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space so I can work with one-dimensional vector space (also if vector space is 'reduced' to a point or line) like a topological space, this is true or not? Only this I need to understand better, thank you Paul

Comment: If you are trying to remove dimensions, then what you want is a Quotient space. Given a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$, we define $v_1 \sim v_2$ if $v_1 - v_2 \in W$. Then "$\sim$" is an equivalence relation on $W$, which then divides $V$ into equilvalence classes: hyperplanes parallel to $W$. These classes can be added to each other (the sum of the hyperplanes containing $v_1$ and $v_2$ will be the hyperplane containing $v_1 + v_2$) and scalar-multiplied (similarly), allowing them to be vectors of a new vector space denoted by $V/W$. This removes every direction parallel to $W$ from $V$.

Comment: mm..thanks, I read about trivial vector space but I see that exist morphism for zero objects https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_object_(algebra)#Vector_space - So, method that you citated is the way to 'remove' dimension. Mm..but..'remove' term seems to be an equivalence term category, not 'remove' thinkable in common meaning

Comment: I used "remove" as a general description only, not as some precise mathematical term. If $V$ has an inner product, then you can define the vector space $W^\perp$ of all vectors in $V$ that are perpendicular to every vector in $W$. Every equivalence class in $V/W$ will contain exactly one element of $W^\perp$ and $W^\perp$ and $V/W$ are isomorphic as vector spaces. So you can think of $V/W$ as being like $W^\perp$, but definable even when you don't have a inner product lying around. The vectors in $V/W$ are pointing away from $W$, the parallel components removed by the equivalence process.

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful clarification